# Roblox mouse not working

Tags: roblox

When I am playing Roblox, I use my mouse to steer the direction of my character. However, After a few turns of the screen, the screen stopped turning, and I cannot steer in that direction anymore. I need to turn my character the other way round in order to continue moving.

Why is that so?

is there a way for me to fix it?

[image: Mouse not working]

(sorry for the poor grammar)

Comment: Do you play the game fullscreen or in a window ?  From what I guess is that your cursor is at the border of your screen and cannot go further (hence, having to turn the other way around). As to how to fix this, I have no clue.

Comment: @Fana I play on a window

Comment: @DREADLORD_XD Try to play in fullscreen.

Comment: Just confirming: you hold down right click and drag the mouse to move the screen?

Comment: @Corsaka   yes, I do

Comment: So can't you just let go of right click, then move the mouse to the centre of the screen, then hold right click again to continue rotating the camera?

Comment: @Corsaka  I tried but this cost me time, since I'm playing intense games like arsenal

Comment: Wait, what? Arsenal should be in first person. The mouse should move regardless of right-click. Your client sounds INCREDIBLY broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to a new tab and then place the mouse in the middle of the screen then switch back to roblox and click the mouse. I don't really know why the mouse we need to click it but you have to else it wont work. And then it should fix the problem.